# Storing Debit Card Information for Online Use

Tags: checkout, pci-dss, pci-compliance

If I need to store Debit Card information, what fields will have to be stored?

For example, with Credit Cards the fields are

- Card Number
- Expiration month/year
- Cardholder's Name
- Zip (sometimes)
- <strike>CCV (sometimes)</strike>

What about for Debit Cards? <strike>Do I need to store a PIN?</strike>

Comment: My personal option is you should understand: https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/ and likely engage a payment processing company. There is substantial liability issues with storing this information and you need to ensure you are meeting them or offloading the responsibility.

Comment: Unfortunately, the payment processing company is not yet decided on for this project. We are required to securely store this information ourselves until that time arrives. My question is, **what fields of information do we need to store so we can charge Debit Cards in the near future?** So far, we have only been handling Credit Cards and ACH, so I don't know the answer for Debit Cards.

Comment: This too is defined by the PCI standards indirectly by how you must store information for payment processing. So given the question I think your answer will be best found by digging into the requirements for storing this information. Answering that question first (IMO) will by necessity answer your question above. Not trying to avoid the question I just 1. do not know the full answer and 2. believe you are asking the wrong question first. I re-tagged the question so someone with more PCI experience will hopefully provide details (or correct my suggestion) :)

Comment: You are NEVER allowed to store the CCV.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are storing CCV, then you are BIG TIME in violation of PCI-DSS.  Never store the CVV, your client will be fined for doing so.

Comment: Same applies to PIN codes - you must not store CCV/CVC codes and PINs under any circumstances!

Answer (score 0):

PIN-based debit cards are a non-factor for online purchasing. Why? Because they require accepting a PIN number *through an encrypted PIN pad (or other encrypted device). You cannot do that with only purchasing, only with face-to-face purchasing.

And, with face-to-face purchases you *cannot* store PIN numbers.